# push_notebook does not work in Google Colab Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, slider, bokeh, google-colaboratory, ipywidgets

I am using bokeh on Google colab. I wonder if anybody has used push_notebook in Google Collab Jupyter notebook. I am trying to run the following code in Jupiter Notebook on Google Colab , but it gets stuck on push_notebook() command

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import push_notebook,show,output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
output_notebook()

x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,2000)
y=np.sin(x)
p=figure(title="ff",plot_height=300,plot_width=600,y_range=(-5,5))
r=p.line(x,y,color="red",line_width=2)
def update(f,w=1,A=1,phi=0):
   print("fff")
   if f== "sin":func=np.sin
   if f== "sin":func=np.sin
   elif f=="cos":func =np.cos
   elif f== "tan":func=np.tan
   r.data_source.data['y']=A*func(w*x+phi) 
   push_notebook()
show(p,notebook_handle=True)
interact(update,f=["sin","cos","tan"],w=(0,100),A=(1,5),phi=(0,20,0.1))
```

Can anybody suggest what's wrong with the code and how it can be run on Google Colab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`push_notebook` does not and cannot work on Google Collab due to the fact that Google's notebook implementation will not allow the necessary websocket connections to be opened. There is nothing that can be done about this until/unless Google makes changes on their end.

ref: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9302

Comment: thnx in that case can you also  comment how to use bokeh control ,fr example in this case i want to change figure graph on slider control,

Comment: I don't think that is currently possible in Collab. Evidently they are working on updating things on the Google side (see latest comments in the linked issue) so there is some hope for the future. But until they make their changes, and we make updated releases to use those changes, these sorts of features can only be supported in classic notebook and JupyterLab. The best you might be able to do is `show` an entirely new plot every time the slider updates. Not certain that would work, though.